# SSRS error after adding "total page numbers" in hidden fields?

Tags: reporting-services, page-numbering

After I added two hidden text-boxes in the header and footer of my report, as shown here:
[image]

Then I got the following error:

[image]

which reads:

> An error occurred during local report processing. The definition of
>   the report  /RPT_Resp_Answr is invalid. The tablix 'Tablix2' has a
>   detail member with inner members. Detail members can contain only
>   static inner members.

I'm confused at the part that says " Detail members can contain only static inner members" - is that referring to the page # part?

Comment: I don't think its related to the textbox containing TotalPage expression .The error states that you have a dynamic object which you are trying to nest inside another dynamic row . R u getting  any error if u remove the hidden text box ?

Comment: @praveen - Hmm, actually - yes I am getting the same error when I remove the hidden text box, so that's a clue. OK let me think hard thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out now, when I tabbed into the "Tablix member" , there was a specifically referenced "detail  member" under the "Row Groups" section.

[image]

So then I click the arrow ad say "Delete grop"